# Collabnet subversion edge doesn't show repositories

Tags: svn, subversion-edge, collabnet

I created a repository using a new subversion edge installation. However, it doesn't show up on the list of respositories (even if I do a load or discover). If I try to make the repository again, it tells me a repository already exists with that name. I've checked permissions, and permissions are

```
[/]
* = rw
```

So it shouldn't be a permission issue.

I don't know what else could prevent me from seeing the repositories. Suggestions?

Comment: Seeing them where? Through the web interface?

Comment: Yea, through the web interface. I can see the folders in file explorer, but not in the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that repositories have correct ownership

user: svnadmin
group: svnadmin